# GSON store Json key in String variable

Tags: java, android, parsing, annotations, gson

so I have this one problem with Gson I just cannot figure out.

Imagine a Json structure for handling tickets. The Json looks like this:

```
{
    "concertTicket" : { ... some valid json object ... }
}
```

I wrote my parser like this:

```
@SerializedName("concertTicket")
JsonObject ticketContent;
```

This is simple. Now I have a JsonObject called `ticketContent` that stores the ticket related stuff.

So far so good... now there are exactly three different kinds of tickets: let's assume `concertTicket`, `planeTicket` and `museumTicket`.

What I want to achieve is a Parser with two variables. One storing the `ticketType` and another one storing the `ticketContents`.

I figured out the parser for the `ticketContent`:

```
@SerializedName(value="concertTicket", alternate={"planeTicket", "museumTicket"})
JsonObject ticketContent;
```

My question is now: Is it possible to write an annotation that returns the Json-Key as String in a variable called `ticketType`? Like so:

```
@ ... what to put here ? ...
String ticketType;
```

So that

if its a `concertTicket`, the value of `ticketType = "concertTicket"`,
if its a `planeTicket`, the value of `ticketType = "planeTicket"` and
if its a `museumTicket`, the value of `ticketType = "museumTicket"`?

--- Here is my workaround ---

```
@SerializedName( "concertTicket" )
private JsonObject concertTicket;
@SerializedName( "planeTicket" )
private JsonObject planeTicket;
@SerializedName( "museumTicket" )
private JsonObject museumTicket;

public enum TicketType {
    concertTicket, planeTicket, museumTicket
}

/*
 * since only one of the TicketTypes can be not null, return this as TicketType
 */
public TicketType getTicketType() {
    if ( concertTicket != null ) {
        return TicketType.concertTicket;
    }
    if ( planeTicket != null ) {
        return TicketType.planeTicket;
    }
    if ( museumTicket != null ) {
        return TicketType.museumTicket;
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * since only one of the TicketTypes can be not null, return this as content
 */
public JsonObject getTicketContent() {
    if ( concertTicket != null ) {
        return concertTicket;
    }
    if ( planeTicket != null ) {
        return planeTicket;
    }
    if ( museumTicket != null ) {
        return museumTicket;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 tickets, lets say:
**concertTicket, planeTicket and museumTicket**
then the should have a common parent/super class in common, or an Interface...

if so; then you can **deserialize** to the interface and then cast to the ticket type..

## Example:

```
interface Iticket {
    void printTicket();
}


public class Ticket implements Iticket {
    protected String id;
    protected int price;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ticketString = "{\"id\":\"0000\", \"price\":15}";
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Ticket c = g.fromJson(ticketString, Concert.class);
    ((Concert) c).jump();
    Ticket m = g.fromJson(ticketString, Museum.class);
    ((Museum) m).niddle();

    }

    @Override
    public void printTicket() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

class Concert extends Ticket implements Iticket {

    @Override
    public void printTicket() {
    //
    System.out.println("Loud printer");
    }

    public void jump() {
    System.out.println("jump");
    }
}

class Museum extends Ticket implements Iticket {

    @Override
    public void printTicket() {
    System.out.println("Boring printer");
    }

    public void niddle() {
    System.out.println("niddle");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not arguing that this is not a good idea. But the Json is out of my control. And to clearify, I don't care about the similarities of the classes that come as argument, I only care about the key.